# For loop only sets last iteration

Tags: json, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to load multiple JSON files from an object so that I can just retrieve each set of data from its own respective object. So, for example, for the object below, I want to get the set of data for that particular object selected.

```js
//Key values are the file names and keys are what we use to select which data I wanna get that is stored in "servicesObj"
static var customServices = {EMOTE: "emote_frames", NPC: "npc"};
```

I made a class to handle this

```js
class com.customs.Net.CustomServicesManager {
    
    var customServices, servicesObj, serviceTypeArr, jsonLoader, serviceLoaderArr, serviceTypes, __get__serviceType, arrServicesToLoad, _loadingServiceType;
    public function CustomServicesManager() {
        super();
        trace("Loaded Custom Services Manager");
        servicesObj = {};
        customServices = com.customs.Settings.customServices;       

    }
    function getServiceData(type) {
        var _local2 = servicesObj[type];
        return (_local2);
    }
    public function get serviceType() {
        serviceTypeArr = [];
        for(var i in customServices) {
            serviceTypeArr.push(i);
        }
        return (serviceTypeArr);
    }
    
    public function serviceTypeVal(val) {
        for(var i in customServices) {
            if(i === val) {
                return (customServices[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function loadCustomServices() {
        arrServicesToLoad =  this.__get__serviceType();
        jsonLoader = new com.cp.util.JSONLoader();
        jsonLoader.addEventListener(com.cp.util.JSONLoader.COMPLETE, onCustomServicesJSONLoaded, this);
        loadOngoingServices();
    }
       
   public function loadOngoingServices() {
       if(arrServicesToLoad.length === 0) return (undefined);
        _loadingServiceType = arrServicesToLoad;

       for (var i = 0; i < _loadingServiceType.length; ++i) {
        //for (var i in __get__serviceType()) {
            serviceTypes = _loadingServiceType[i];
            jsonLoader.load(serviceTypeVal(serviceTypes) + ".json");     
        }
    }
 
    public function onCustomServicesJSONLoaded(event) {
        var _local2 = jsonLoader.data;
            servicesObj[serviceTypes] = _local2;
        trace(com.clubpenguin.util.JSONParser.stringify(servicesObj));
     // trace(servicesObj["NPC"]["130_npc"].uniqueId);

     // trace(servicesObj["EMOTE"].frame_menu_id);
      trace(servicesObj["NPC"]["130_npc"].uniqueId);
    }
    

}
```

Each JSON object should be stored in `servicesObj` along with the `serviceType`. That way, I can retrieve their own set of data, like this: `servicesObj["NPC"] ["130_npc"].uniqueId`, but for some reason it only sets the last index in the object **NPC**, and I can't access EMOTE unless using NPC.

These are the results from `servicesObj` where everything is stored

```json
{"NPC":[{"disabled":true,"emote_name":"Laughing Face","frame_menu_id":1,"frame_balloon_id":1},{"emote_name":"Smiley","frame_menu_id":2,"frame_balloon_id":2},{"emote_name":"Coffee Cup","frame_menu_id":3,"frame_balloon_id":13},{"emote_name":"Straight Face","frame_menu_id":4,"frame_balloon_id":3},{"emote_name":"Frown","frame_menu_id":5,"frame_balloon_id":4},{"emote_name":"Game","frame_menu_id":6,"frame_balloon_id":18},{"emote_name":"Surprise","frame_menu_id":7,"frame_balloon_id":5},{"emote_name":"Sticking Out Tongue","frame_menu_id":8,"frame_balloon_id":6},{"emote_name":"Popcorn","frame_menu_id":9,"frame_balloon_id":29},{"emote_name":"Wink","frame_menu_id":10,"frame_balloon_id":7},{"emote_name":"Green Sickly Face","frame_menu_id":11,"frame_balloon_id":8},{"emote_name":"Pizza","frame_menu_id":12,"frame_balloon_id":24},{"disabled":true,"emote_name":"Red Angry Face","frame_menu_id":13,"frame_balloon_id":9},{"emote_name":"Sad Face","frame_menu_id":14,"frame_balloon_id":10},{"emote_name":"Ice Cream","frame_menu_id":15,"frame_balloon_id":26},{"emote_name":"Meh Face","frame_menu_id":16,"frame_balloon_id":11},{"emote_name":"Cake","frame_menu_id":17,"frame_balloon_id":28},{"emote_name":"Clover","frame_menu_id":18,"frame_balloon_id":17},{"emote_name":"Heart","frame_menu_id":19,"frame_balloon_id":30},{"emote_name":"Lightbulb","frame_menu_id":20,"frame_balloon_id":12},{"emote_name":"Flower","frame_menu_id":21,"frame_balloon_id":16},{"emote_name":"Skull","frame_menu_id":22,"frame_balloon_id":40},{"emote_name":"Shocked Face","frame_menu_id":23,"frame_balloon_id":41},{"emote_name":"The Nigger","frame_menu_id":24,"frame_balloon_id":42},{"emote_name":"Pink Flower","frame_menu_id":25,"frame_balloon_id":43}]}
{"NPC":{"130_npc":{"isEnabled":true,"itemsObj":{"total_membership_days":0,"is_member":1,"frame":0,"y_corr":100,"x_corr":100,"photo_id":0,"flag_id":0,"feet":0,"hand":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"face":0,"head":0,"colour_id":0},"bitmask":1,"username":"[NPC] Pelican","uniqueId":9000251},"100_npc":{"isEnabled":true,"itemsObj":{"total_membership_days":0,"is_member":1,"frame":0,"y_corr":256,"x_corr":467,"photo_id":0,"flag_id":0,"feet":0,"hand":0,"body":467,"neck":256,"face":26,"head":0,"colour_id":8},"bitmask":1,"username":"[NPC] Bob","uniqueId":9000234}}}
```

First part needs to be `EMOTE` not NPC but the 2nd part is right.

Comment: It's actionscript 2

Comment: ok, so not javascript

Comment: A js answer would be acceptable too since AS and JS are similar. I just need an idea on what exactly im doing wrong.

Comment: I don't remember **AS2** that much, you also use some custom library classes, but here's the guess. In your **loadCustomServices** method you create several **JSONLoader** instances, but you assign each and every one of them to a single variable (the **jsonLoader**). In the end, you store only the last one created. Then, **Flash Player** probably just **Garbage Collect** the ones that are no longer stored anywhere, and that's why they are destroyed before they have chance to load anything. As a side note, you cannot be sure that this **JSONLoader** even supports  concurrent loading.

Comment: Yeah but `serviceType` shows NPC as  well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that `jsonLoader` and couldn't find any information about it, but a few things seem strange

```
jsonLoader.addEventListener(com.cp.util.JSONLoader.COMPLETE, onCustomServicesJSONLoaded, this);
```

leaves the impression, that the `jsonLoader` works asynchronous, ie you start it, and some time later, the eventhandler is called.

Then you do

```
for (var i = 0; i < _loadingServiceType.length; ++i) {
    serviceTypes = _loadingServiceType[i];
    jsonLoader.load(serviceTypeVal(serviceTypes) + ".json");     
}
```

ie start a bunch of concurrent loading operations. As the loader seems asynchronous, the loop isn't waiting for the `load` operation to finish, before it starts the next one, but just rushes through them all. Don't know if the loader supports this, but let's assume it does. And then comes the eventhandler (I removed all the logging and tracing statements)

```
public function onCustomServicesJSONLoaded(event) {
    var _local2 = jsonLoader.data;
    servicesObj[serviceTypes] = _local2;
}
```

Here you are not accessing the data from the `event`, but the property `jsonLoader.data` (ie a property of the single `jsonLoader` instance) itself. I really don't get how that would work in an asynchronous environment. Maybe the loader sets `this.data` before raising the event so this might in fact for each finished loading set the correct data object, you can then access.

But the bigger problem is, you are using the `serviceTypes` variable to determine the key for the new data block. But as this `serviceTypes` variable is contained in the class it can only have a single value. And this value is updated in each iteration of the `for` loop, where you start the load operations. And as this loop is long finished, before the first file has finished loading, the value of `serviceTypes` is of course always the last value it was set to, ie the last value in the `_loadingServiceType` array.

As I said, I don't know this JSONLoader class, so I don't know what information you can gather from the `event` in the eventhandler. But you have to find a way to pass the information about which file the current event applies to. If that is not possible, you have to serialize your data reading, ie don't start a new load operation before the current one is finished.

If neither of those possibilities work, can you change the structure of the json you are loading? So you can include the name of the key in the json file. Something like

```
{
   "key": "NPC",
   "data": {
     "130_npc":{ ...}
   }
}
```

Then in your eventhandler do

```
public function onCustomServicesJSONLoaded(event) {
  var key = jsonLoader.data.key;
  var data = jsonLoader.data.data;
  servicesObj[key] = data;
}
```